# Как сделать чтобы, если при валидации error, то возвращает на страницу с параметром laravel?

Tags: laravel, валидация

Всем привет.

Подскажите пжл.
У меня есть страница (web.ru/cat/2)
Когда я нажимаю на кнопку, появляется pop-up (web.ru/cat/2#message_create)

Далее я заполняю форму и отправляю на валидацию:

```
class ShopMessageRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        // зарегистрирован
        if($this->user()){
            return [
                'text'    => 'max:2000',
            ];

        // не зарегистрирован
        }else{
            return [
                'city_id' => 'required',
                'name'    => 'required|max:250',
                'phone'   => 'required|integer|digits:11',
                'email'   => 'required|max:250|email',
                'text'    => 'required|max:2000',
            ];
        }
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'required'  => 'поле обязательно для заполнения.',
            'integer'   => 'поле должно быть числовым.',
            'max'       => 'максимальное число символов - :max.',
            'min'       => 'минимальное число символов - :min.',
            'size'      => 'Поле должно иметь количество символов - :size.',
            'email'     => 'поле должно быть корректным e-mail адресом.',

            'phone.digits' => 'должно быть 11 цифр.',
        ];
    }
}
```

где и как прописать чтобы, если валидация не прошла error, меня перенаправляло обратно на страницу (web.ru/cat/2#message_create) а не на страницу (web.ru/cat/2), т.е чтобы мой pop-up был открыт!!!

Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function rules()
    {
        $this->redirect = url()->previous() . '#shop_message_create';

            return [
                // ....
            ];
    }
```